# Media file item looses blob value after publish

Tags: publishing, media-library

This is in Sitecore 9.1 where I have a pdf file media item in sitecore, that is browsable all good from the CM site (master DB) but when I try to browse to it on the CD site (web DB), it gave me a 404 error.

When I checked the media item on the web DB I noticed that the "Media" field was empty. I went through the logs to check for any publish errors but nothing. I still do not know why this happened.

Comment: What did Sitecore support say?

Comment: Haven't heard back from them yet.

Comment: we are also facing this issue with missing blob-entries in the web database. And we found this working "detach-attach-publish" solution too. Since the project contains a large amount of media items this is not a suitable option for us :( @Debabrata Biswas
Where is this bug documented? I haven't found anything yet. Do you have a reference number from the Sitecore support?

Answer (score 0):

Good news is I did find a solution. On the master DB, for that media item, I first downloaded the file using the download option. I then detached the file and then re-attached using the downloaded file. I then published that media item and now when i go to that media item on the web db, I can see the blob value in the "Media" field. Hope this helps anyone experiencing the same.

Comment: I've also seen cases where I had to delete the item entirely from the web database and republish from master to web.

Comment: Sitecore has come back with a response that it is a bug in Sitecore 9.1 and have documented it.

Comment: @DebabrataBiswas Do you have or can you find the support case number ? i got the exact same issue

Comment: @ThomasStern Sitecore support had provided an internal known issue number but they did not publish it. They simply suggested that we should regularly clean up the blobs table from sitecore control panel. I then ended up writing this blog "http://everydaysitecore.home.blog/2020/06/19/schedule-sitecore-database-cleanup-tasks-programmatically/"so you can automate it.

Comment: @DebabrataBiswas thank you so much

Comment: I actually want to download file but it is showing Blob Value. Is there any way to download and attach that file?

Comment: Yes you should be able to.